# Why `adb install package.apk` asks to remove a file and never removes?

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, apk

I typed:

```
adb install -r my_package.apk
```

Then I saw the following message:

```
Success
rm ro /data/local/tmp/demo.apk (y/N):
```

When I typed `y` and hit enter the shell got stuck forever. **Why**?

Answer (score 0):

The APK on your development machine probably does not have write permissions, and adb preserved the read-only file mode when copying to your device.  adb seems to not feed stdin into the underlying `adb shell rm` command, so the rm hangs on an input it will never receive.

The solution is to run `chmod +w my_package.apk`, then run `adb install -r my_package.apk`.